# Vagrant - Deleting old boxes

Tags: vagrant

```
C:\Users\user\Documents\Code\stores (master -> origin)
λ vagrant box remove --all
Vagrant failed to initialize at a very early stage:

There was an error loading a Vagrantfile. The file being loaded
and the error message are shown below. This is usually caused by
a syntax error.

Path: C:/Users/user/Documents/Code/stores/Vagrantfile
Line number: 0
Message: LoadError: cannot load such file -- C:/Users/user/Documents/Code/stores/vendor/laravel/homestead/scripts/homestead.rb
```

Hello, I am trying to delete some old boxes. the code no longer exists so vagrant is complaining with the above error. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I deleted all the files from C:\Users\user.vagrant.d\boxes